# Drill is not running on CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-drill, mapr

```
bin>sqlline -u "jdbc:drill:zk=zk node1 ip:5181,zk node2 ip:5181,zk node3 ip:5181"
```

I am facing this error while I am running drill

[image]

Comment: "Authentication failed". See e.g. https://maprdocs.mapr.com/52/Drill/connecting_to_a_zookeeper_cluster.html. Also, please [edit] your question and add logs as text, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the authentication failed. If you are using plain authentication to login, you can add `-n username -p password` to your sqlline command to connect.

ie:

```
sqlline -u "jdbc:drill:zk=zk node1 ip:5181,zk node2 ip:5181,zk node3 ip:5181" -n employee -p myloginpassword123
```

Comment: You have encryption enabled on Drillbit side hence you won't be able to connect using username and password. You need to connect using MapRSasl auth mechanism in this case or disable sasl encryption on server side and just have authentication instead of it.